# wordpress og:image featured image

Tags: wordpress, facebook, image, wordpress-featured-image

Basically, I am using facebook markup on my website.

If an article has more than one image the facebook markup doesn't pick up the featured image for sharing, but does with only one image in the article.

I would like the facebook markup to pick up featured image no matter how many images are in the article?

Here is my markup:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php if (function_exists('wp_get_attachment_thumb_url')) {echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); }?>" />
```

Does anyone know what needs changing?

Problem has been driving me nuts.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using any SEO plugin and want to do it in code, you might put this inside your `<head>` tags, probably in `header.php` of your theme

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'large'); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Where `large` selects the resized media size, you might want to play with the dimensions or even define custom media size to match facebook's [dimension recommendations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images/).

Comment: how to make wordpress use the image feature on the og image and when the home screen it will take the default image

Comment: I believe you can use ```<?php if(!is_front_page() && !is_home() && has_post_thumbnail()) : ?><meta property="og:image" content="(echo thumbnail url here)"/><?php endif; ?>```

Comment: thank you for answering. Sorry I've used this code in the header but the og image doesn't appear on the homepage or in the article. is there any other solution?

Comment: Now I see that you probably want to render some other image on homepage. Then try this: ```<?php if(!is_front_page() && !is_home() && has_post_thumbnail()) : ?><meta property="og:image" content="(echo thumbnail url here)"/><?php else : ?><meta property="og:image" content="http://url_to_some_default_image.jpg"/><?php endif; ?>```

Answer (score 0):

OG images can be tricky...

Make sure that there are no duplicate OG image tags, YOAST SEO also creates OG Image tags and some other SEO plugins might do the same.

I have seen that this confuses Facebook.

Just check your source code to see that the correct image is echoed in the OG tag.

Lastly use the [Facebook debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) to see if you pick up any problems.

Comment: There is no duplication of the OG Tags, only problem is that og:image tags is pulling the image from the article rather than the feature image

Just wondered what the line of code be to pull featured image?